# How to custom the Android default Auto-Brightness Array Values?

Tags: android, android-sensors, lcd, screen-brightness

As we know , the android system realizing logic of the auto-brightness is like this(By LightSensor):

frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/power/DisplayPowerController.java

```
public DisplayPowerController(Looper looper, Context context, Notifier notifier,
    LightsService lights, TwilightService twilight,
    DisplayBlanker displayBlanker,
    Callbacks callbacks, Handler callbackHandler) {
        if (mUseSoftwareAutoBrightnessConfig) { 
            int[] lux = resources.getIntArray(
                com.android.internal.R.array.config_autoBrightnessLevels);
        int[] screenBrightness = resources.getIntArray(
                com.android.internal.R.array.config_autoBrightnessLcdBacklightValues);
        }

    }

private final SensorEventListener mLightSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (mLightSensorEnabled) {
            final long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final float lux = event.values[0];
            handleLightSensorEvent(time, lux);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Not used.
    }
};
```

frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml

```
<integer-array name="config_autoBrightnessLevels">
</integer-array>

<integer-array name="config_autoBrightnessLcdBacklightValues">
</integer-array>
```

I want to custom the config_autoBrightnessLevels in my own app(when launch the APP , make the LCD more brighter), So how to do it ? Must I copy the realizing logic into my APP and update the WindowManager.LayoutParams.screenBrightness value ?